# How to use contracts in attachments

Tags: corda

I uploaded contract jar from rpc shell. And then used the hash in the transaction builder

```
val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
    .addOutputState(
        TransactionState(
            dummyState, 
            "com.example.contract.SampleContract", 
            notary, 
            null,
            HashAttachmentConstraint(SecureHash.parse(hashId))
        )
    )
    .addCommand(txCommand)
```

On running this flow, I see the below error in the notary log:

> net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractConstraintRejection:
>   Contract constraints failed for com.example.contract.SampleContract,
>   transaction:
>   781CC5C14E9DC7642B3C7F12177CB79C5EADE0D7F2033F56DB6909E1F2199C42

The SecureHash of my uploaded jar is "05A2B667D5DDE42A632EF0A9810D5CE90B3F31BFF62E0539C11C9DEB0FAC2430". This is different from the one seen in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

`CordaRPCOps.uploadAttachment` should not be used for contract JARs. Contract JARs should be added to the node by adding the JAR files to the node's `cordapps` folder and restarting the node. If the notary is a validating notary, they will also require a copy of the contract JAR.

`CordaRPCOps.uploadAttachment` should only be used for attachments containing supporting information for a transaction. These attachments *are* propagated automatically and are added to transactions using the `TransactionBuilder.addAttachment` method.

Comment: thanks joel. I was reading https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html and i see an example with an explicitly specified hash constraint from within a flow. I was trying to do something similar.